# Iterate over empty fields and append text, with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, iteration

let's assume we have a simple form with multiple input fields and let's say all of them have the class name "check_me".

I want to iterate over the fields and do the following:

- If the field values are all empty - do nothing
- If at least one of the fields is not empty, append "0" to all remaining empty fields
- If all fields are not empty, do nothing.

Those checks should fire upon form submit.

Comment: Have you even tried to do it yourself yet?

Comment: Yes, and I came to nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is what you want

```
var empty = true;
$(".check_me").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "")
        {empty = false;}
});

if(!empty)
{
    $(".check_me").each(function() {

        if($(this).val() == "")
        {
            $(this).val(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you - does just what I wanted.